# Gradle build error: cannot access ITest bad class file: ITest.class default method found in version 50.0 classfile

Tags: java, android, junit, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I have strange problem and don't know how to resolve it.

I have an interface with default method, like this:

```
public interface ITest{
    default String getText(){
       return "ITest";
    }
}
```

and class which implements this interface, like this:

```
public class TestClasssss implements ITest{
    private String text;
}
```

And I trying to use this class inside my app unit tests project.

So, if I copy this classes inside my android's unit test project it compiles ok and all working as expected, however if this class and interface declared in app source folder, application do not compile and crash with

```
Error:(30, 10) error: cannot access ITest bad class file: ~\ITest.class
default method found in version 50.0 classfile
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

So, how could I fix this strange behaviour?

---

My graddle config looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.projectname"
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/controls',
                            'src/main/res/fragments',
                            'src/main/res/activities',
                            'src/main/res/views',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
}

ext {
    JUNIT_VERSION = '4.12'
    DAGGER_VERSION = '2.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.111-beta'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.1"

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.2.3'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
    compile('eu.davidea:flexible-adapter:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        changing = true
    }
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.5.1@aar'
    compile "cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2"
    compile 'net.sf.biweekly:biweekly:0.5.0'

    //Dagger dependencies started
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    testCompile "junit:junit:$JUNIT_VERSION"
    testApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    //Dagger dependencies finished

    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10'
}
```

Comment: This code not compile only if TestClasssss used in tests, if you remove it from test project compile correctly, am I right?

Comment: With this fake example - yes, that's correct. But in real case it's fails only when I trying to access methods from interface or if trying to create a mock for those class.

Comment: @silent_coder Do you use retrolambda in your project?

Comment: Yes, retrolambda is used

Comment: can you show your `gradle` code?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set up [source and target](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_convention_properties) compatibility correctly

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: I have those settings.

Comment: @silent_coder is your problem reproduceable in both android studio and gradle commandline?

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue, it appears to be some kind of conflict between the compiled java source version accepted on android and the output produced by the code compiled with retrolambda.
The problem raises when you use the `default` notation for funcional interfaces method.
There's some kind of limited support for that in the retrolambda plugin, quoting the readme of the repo ([orfjackal/retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)):

> retrolambda.defaultMethods
>         Whether to backport default methods and static methods on interfaces.
>         LIMITATIONS: All backported interfaces and all classes which implement
>         them or call their static methods must be backported together,
>         with one execution of Retrolambda.
>         Disabled by default. Enable by setting to "true"

So you can try using this in your android module's `build.gradle` file:

```
...
android {
...
}
retrolambda {
    defaultMethods = true
}
```

In my case this does not work, but my scenario was quite different than yours. I was having the retrolambda code on one library project and then trying to use that on another app project.

Also I could not get the Jack & Jill compiler to work (theres some kind of java8 support with Jack enabled, see [Enable Java 8 Features and the Jack Toolchain](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#configuration) at android reference), one cryptic "NullPointer" raises at `./gradlew assembleDebug`, so I suggest to avoid `jackOptions` for now.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you probably need to enable the `Jack` compiler. You need the following:

- Android Studio > 2.1
- Default methods **are only available** if you are **targetting API Level 24**

Your gradle needs to look something like this:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

This is the [Java 8 Language Feature Page in the Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

Comment: Why it's compiled without problems in non test enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after using dex2jar. According to https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/blob/master/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes.java#L264, version 50 of the JVM bytecode represents Java 1.6, while my dex file was designed to run on version 52 (1.8). I used another dex2jar utility (which should work on any jar, not just dex) to change the version to 1.8. The source is at https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/blob/2.x/dex-tools/src/main/java/com/googlecode/dex2jar/tools/ClassVersionSwitch.java, the command is `d2j-class-version-switch.sh 8 <source jar> <destination jar>`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that your gradle build is using jdk1.8+? It seems like the build is trying to utilize a class that was built using 1.8 but being tested during build using a lower version.

try:

```
gradle clean build
```

OR

```
gradlew clean build
```

Comment: Yep, it's look strange. Your command behave the same as usual android studio builds and don't fix the problem. It's fails on :app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Android Studio try to Clean Project, then Build project. If it doesn't help too, then Click to File -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart". It must help

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this don't help.